# How do I get rid of stumps?

Tags: story-of-seasons

So I cut down some trees on my property, but there are still stumps there. How do I get rid of them, so I can use the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the axe some more!  Cutting down the tree causes your farmer to spin.  Just working on a stump will be the usual action, but I believe spins will still count for stump removal. It will take two or three chops for the stump to convert itself into more lumber for you.

Comment: spinning does not count for stump removal, you have to stop spinning then swing. (just tested)